# Java oop trying to reduce a type of an object in game app

Tags: java, oop, casting, polymorphism

https://github.com/cesarMark/psGame?files=1

So each player has health points but the problem is that I cannot reduce for example if an opponent is attacking another opponent . and then tried to cast 'i' as the victim that will be attacked

```
Character[] gamePlayers = new Character[3];
    gamePlayers[0] = new Bob();
    gamePlayers[1] = new Alice();
    gamePlayers[2] = new EvilTom();
        for(Character i:gamePlayers) {
            if(i instanceof Player) {
                System.out.println("Hello "+i.getClass().getName()+"!"+" Here is your status \n"+i.toString());
                System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
                System.out.println("1)shoot\n2)reload\n3)sleep");
                System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
                int number = input.nextInt();
                switch(number) {
                case 1:
                        System.out.println("Hi "+((Player) i).getName()+" Who would you like to shoot at?");
                        for(Character j:gamePlayers) {
                            System.out.println(j.toString());
                        }
                        int attackChoice = input.nextInt();
                        switch(attackChoice) {
                            case 1:
                                if(i instanceof Alice) {
                                    ((Alice) i).fire();
                                    System.out.println("BOB");
                                    //Now in this line our case Bob is getting shot by Alice . Now in the class of Bob I specified int health meaning that I'm trying to reduce his life like objectOfBob.health-- how can I do it after Alice shoots? (BTW the fire() comes from an interface that the players implement 
                                }
```

;

As you can see where I put the comment 
Bob is getting shot by Alice .
 Now in the class of Bob I specified int health meaning that I'm trying to reduce his life like objectOfBob.health-- 
how can I do it after Alice shoots?
 (BTW the fire() comes from an interface that the players implement)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java oop, trying to reduce life in a variable of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808151/java-oop-trying-to-reduce-life-in-a-variable-of-an-object)

Comment: yes it is a duplicate it is also in my account because it was closed so it says to open another one and i tried to specify more